# How to extend react-router Router class with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying to extend react-router Router class like this:

```
class RouterWrapper extends Router {
    componentWillMount() {
        super.componentWillMount();
    }
}
```

so I have got a typescript compilation error
`TS2339: Property 'componentWillMount' does not exist on type 'Component<RouterProps, ComponentState>'`. All necessary typings are installed.
At now I have found workaround:

```
class PatchRouter extends Router {
    componentWillMount?();
}
```

Then extends from `PatchRouter`, but this solution so ugly.

So, here is my question:
How properly extends Router using typescript 2.2?

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node dev-server.js",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "^2.0.45",
    "@types/react": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.19",
    "@types/react-router": "^2.0.44",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "dom-helpers": "^3.2.0",
    "jss": "^6.2.0",
    "jss-camel-case": "^3.0.0",
    "jss-default-unit": "^5.0.2",
    "jss-nested": "^3.0.1",
    "jss-vendor-prefixer": "^4.0.0",
    "memory-fs": "^0.4.1",
    "mobx": "^3.0.1",
    "mobx-react": "^4.1.0",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "^4.2.11",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-router": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.0-dev.20161208",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.6",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not helpful as an answer, but what are you trying to achieve? Facebook don't recommend component class inheritance, perhaps there is an alternative solution? - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance

Comment: @T-Mitchell I read this [article](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.457jqmqgq) and as I understood there is only one way to modify componentWillMount behavior using extends. Сorrect me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you can write own router incase  using HTML5 pushState and hash